# Lost mobile movie uploads to Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I moved 17 full-length movies from my HTC phone to my Dropbox account using a desktop in an Internet cafe. I had to download Dropbox in that particular computer b/c it didn't have one, I dragged and dropped the movies and checked it afterwards,  it was playing.  Since it was a public computer,  I uninstalled the Dropbox afterwards.

I then opened my Dropbox account using Chrome browser but couldn't find my movies inside the new folder that I created. I checked the new folder in my Dropbox account using my mobile phone in its Dropbox app. but no luck.

Do you think I can still recover the movies? I'm thinking of going back to the Internet cafe and install Recuva in that particular desktop computer to try recovery but I haven't had the time yet.  The movies aren't in my mobile anymore because I needed the space which was the reason I moved them to my Dropbox account.

Comment: Contact Dropbox support to see we hat can be done recovery of the f iles are unlikely if it's been more than a couple hours

Comment: Thanks but I did the transfer like a month ago. Have a nice day.

Comment: We're not a forum. Assuming its something thats on topic as per the [help] you can generally ask it as a seperate question, though I don't think it is.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the size 17 movies would be, chances are they were never uploaded - dropbox does have to respect physics and available bandwidth, and even at fairly horrid quality, that would be several gigabytes.

As for recovering it from the cybercafe, considering the time period, there's a decent chance that the space that the movies were on may have been used for other things, that makes recovery difficult - and space that was used for other things cannot be be recovered from. Thats assuming the cybercafe dosen't periodically wipe the system or use something like deep freeze to protect it.

tldr: Don't bother with recovery.